# How to check if @RequestParam is empty or not?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two pages, the first has a form with hidden fields  which send parameters to the second one. I want to return an error message if the user go to the second page while the form with hidden fields is empty, so for doing that i tried that but it's not working:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/generate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String FicheService(@ModelAttribute Movement movement,@RequestParam("nom") String nom, @RequestParam("number") Integer number,ModelMap model){


   if(nom=="" && number == null) { model.addAttribute("errorMessage",true);
                               return "firstPage";
                              }
   else { return "secondPage";}


}
```

How to check if @RequestParam is empty or not?

Comment: You can user @NotEmpty annotation for such validations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the `@RequestParam`, with a `required` attribute value of `false`:

```
@RequestParam(value="nom", required=false)
```

and then check the null condition the way you have done.